# How to make the bot ignores giving me coins when using the !coins command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I was doing the coins system but I have faced a small problem.
Normally I get 1 coin whenever I type something, but I do not want the bot to give me coins when I use the !coins command to check how many coins I have. 
I want it to ignore giving me coins when using this command.
So what should I add?

This is my code in index.js:

```
if (message.channel.id === "528734148718886922"){
 if(!coins[message.author.id]){
   coins[message.author.id] = {
     coins: 0
   };
 }

 let coinAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
 let baseAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
 console.log(`${coinAmt}; ${baseAmt}`);

 if(coinAmt === baseAmt){
   coins[message.author.id] = {
     coins: coins[message.author.id].coins + coinAmt
   };
   fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
     if (err) console.log(err)
   }); 

   let coinEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
   .setAuthor(message.author.username)
   .setColor("#6666ff")
   .addField("", `You earned ${coinAmt} Scrap`)

   message.channel.send(coinEmbed).then(message => {message.delete(100000)});

   }
 }
```

coins.js file:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) =>{
    //coins

    if(!coins[message.author.id]){
        coins[message.author.id] = {
            coins: 0
        };
    }

    let uCoins = coins[message.author.id].coins;

    let coinEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setColor("#6666ff")
    .addField("", uCoins);



    message.channel.send(coinEmbed).then(message => {message.delete(50000)});


}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "coins"
}
```

Comment: maybe something like `if(message.content === "!coin")` ...?

Answer (score -1):

I guess easiest way would be to just replace  `if (message.channel.id === "528734148718886922"){` with:

```
if (message.channel.id === "528734148718886922" && message.content !== "!coin"){`
```

Another way, which is a bit more complex but allows you to do more would be to only give coins if no command was found.
Differing on how you built your bot you probably have an `if(cmd) {` or an `if(commandfile)`, or something else in that fashion, you can then just put the coin code into the `else` part so that coins are only given if no command was run.

Answer (score -1):

you could run the coin giving code LAST and run all commands before.
and WHEN `!coins` is ran. You can skip the coin code.

```
var giveCoins = true;
function giveCoinsFunction(ID){...}
function ranWhenMessageIsSent(m){
    giveCoins = true;

    if(m.content.toLowerCase() === `!coins`){
        giveCoins = false;
        coins.run(bot,m,m.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    }

    if(giveCoins) giveCoinsFunction(m.author.id);
}
```